# Monty Hall Game

Tags: java, logic, probability

I'm a new programmer currently in the process of learning Java. I've got a game here based on the game Let's make a deal & the monty hall problem (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhlc7peGlGg) and I've been having issues with the logic for this code. Everything seems to be working right except that I can't seem to get the user_door to switch to the other door and determine if they are a winner correctly. If anybody can help me understand what I'm doing wrong here I would love to take this opportunity to learn, thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GameShow {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random generator = new Random();

    // Initialize Variables
    int user_door,
        open_door,
        other_door,
        prize_door;

    // Generate random value 1-3
    prize_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
    open_door = prize_door;

    while(open_door == prize_door){
        open_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
    }

    other_door = open_door;

    while (other_door == open_door || other_door == prize_door){
        other_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
    }

    // Begin Game
    System.out.println("*** Welcome to the game show! ***");  
    System.out.println("Select the door (1, 2, or 3): ");
    user_door = scan.nextInt();


    // User Validation
        if (user_door > 3 || user_door < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please select door 1, 2, or 3");
            user_door = scan.nextInt();
        } else if(user_door == 1 || user_door == 2 ||  user_door == 3) {

    //Continue Game
    System.out.println("\nIn a moment, I will show you where the prize is located,");
    System.out.println("but first I will show you what is behind one of the other doors");

    //Continue Dialogue
    System.out.println("\nBehind door number " + open_door + " are goats!");
    System.out.println("You selected door number " + user_door);
    System.out.println("\nWould you like to switch your door(y/n)? ");

    //User Input Yes or No
    char userReply = scan.next().charAt(0);

    //If statement with nested while statements for user input
        if (userReply == 'y'){
                user_door = other_door;
                } while(userReply != 'y' && userReply != 'n')
                {
                    //User Validation
                    System.out.println("Please enter either y/n");
                    userReply = scan.next().charAt(0);
                } 

    System.out.println("The prize is behind door number: " + prize_door); 

    //Check to see if user won or lost
        if(user_door == prize_door){
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You won the prize!");
            } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry. You lost.");
                    }       

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a debugger and step through the code line by line to see at which point exactly the program deviates from your expectation of what it should do?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: I'm doing a code review through your work at the moment. It's a bit longer to track the problem, so I will explain some of the things that you could optimize on in a few minutes.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, to see the variables go to Window -> Show View -> Variables, or alternatively press Alt+Shift+Q,V

Comment: Yes I'm on eclipse and will try that out asap! Thanks for the help

Comment: If you're worried about other people on your class sharing your code, don't post your code on a public site on the internet. Trying to edit out the answers of everyone involved after you get your answer to avoid anyone else from learning the same things you did is against SO policy. Besides even then people can see the source code by looking at edit history.

Comment: @Kamhl Even if it is edited they is a public edit history which is available for the google search engine and it is against SO policy as t0mppa mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You never properly assign the other door. The other door you've assigned is a random number, and also your implementation does not properly describe the Monty Hall Problem.

#### An Example that Breaks the Program

So let's say prize door = 1, open door = 2, then other door = 3 by default.

Let's say the user picks door 2. Then, when door 2 is open, there's actually 2 possible other doors: 1 and 3.

A key part of the Monty Hall Problem is that a door the *user has not selected* is opened.

When you select the user's door, you need to determine what the other_door is then. This code was a bit hard to follow, so I'll go over some issues I found while attempting to find your issue.

#### Prize Door Generation

```
// Generate random value 1-3
prize_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1; //assigns a value to the prize
open_door = prize_door;

while(open_door == prize_door){
    open_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1; //assigns a value to the door to open, not the prize
}

other_door = open_door;

while (other_door == open_door || other_door == prize_door){
    other_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1; //assigns the last value to this
}
```

This code assigns the prize_door properly, but the rest doesn't need to be done yet. We can simplify its implementation to this.

```
prize_door = generator.nextInt(3) + 1; //we know what the prize is
```

This is easier to manage than 3 variables, and less dependent on randomness. We only need to track the chooser's door, and the door which the prize is behind.

#### Getting the User's Door

```
user_door = -1; //instantiate to -1 here

// User Validation
while (user_door > 3 || user_door < 0) {
    System.out.println("Please select door 1, 2, or 3");
    user_door = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Your user validation will fail if I try to enter 4 after being told not to. You should lock them in the loop until they pick a door.

This also removes your need for an if, because the number will be 1, 2, or 3 once it leaves the loop

#### Getting the Door to Open

At this point, we have two numbers instantiated.

```
System.out.println("\nBehind door number " + open_door + " are goats!");
System.out.println("You selected door number " + user_door);
```

At this point in the original Monty Hall Game, you're supposed to open a door that the chooser has not selected. The user's door is never opened. In this case, we have two inputs, user_door and prize_door
Using cheesy logic, we can determine which door to open by adding them together, or you can do a true if to verify. I will present cheesy since it's faster to write and still makes sense.

```
if(prize_door + user_door == 4) { // 1 and 3
    open_door = 2;
}
else if(prize_door + user_door == 5) { // 2 and 3
    open_door = 1;
}
else { //1 and 2
    open_door = 3;
}
```

The non-cheesy option is:

```
boolean oneIsTaken = false;
boolean twoIsTaken = false;

if(prize_door == 1 || user_door == 1) {
    oneIsTaken = true;
}
if(prize_door == 2 || user_door == 2) {
    twoIsTaken = true;
}

if(oneIsTaken && twoIsTaken) {
    open_door = 3;
}
else if(oneIsTaken) {
    open_door = 2;
}
else {
    open_door = 1;
}
```

#### Getting the Door that you can Switch To

Using the open door and the user's original door, we can select the switched door, as the door these two aren't is the one you will switch to.

```
if(open_door + user_door == 4) { // 1 and 3
    user_door = 2;
}
else if(open_door + user_door == 5) { // 2 and 3
    user_door = 1;
}
else { //1 and 2
    user_door = 3;
}
```

#### Determining whether the user has won

Same as before:

```
    if(user_door == prize_door){
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You won the prize!");
        } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry. You lost.");
                }       

    }
```

No issues with this.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try to go over this and try to implement it

Comment: But... this is also wrong. A: The whole implementation, cheesy or noncheesy, don't take into consideration the scenario where the user picks the **correct** door the **first** time. If I pick door 2, which also has the prize behind it, then `if(prize_door + user_door == 4) { // 1 and 3
    open_door = 2;
}` that door will also be opened! B: If you pick the correct door, one of the other two doors should **randomly** be chosen. If I pick door 2, and door 3 opens, I know the prize is behind door 1, because if the prize were behind door 2 as well, door 1 would have opened!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what Srikanth said above. The thing that is missing is the part where you test the user reply. you should switch the "if" and "while" statements. This will help solve your door switching problem.

Before

```
 if (userReply == 'y')
     {
     user_door = other_door;
     }  
 while(userReply != 'y' && userReply != 'n')
     {
     //User Validation
     System.out.println("Please enter either y/n");
     userReply = scan.next().charAt(0);
     }
```

Change to

```
 while(userReply != 'y' && userReply != 'n')
    {
        //User Validation
        System.out.println("Please enter either y/n");
        userReply = scan.next().charAt(0);
    }
 if (userReply == 'y')
    {
     user_door = other_door;
    }
```

The way you were doing it only check the first time a character was entered. If they did it wrong and tried to do it again, then it would not switch the door because you were past that part of the program.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some code optimisation and importantly I've solved it. The mistakes you made in your code will be explained below.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class table {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();

        // Initialize Variables
        int user_door, open_door, other_door, prize_door;

        // Generate random value 1-3
        prize_door = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;
        other_door = prize_door;

        // Begin Game
        System.out.println("*** Welcome to the game show! ***");

        // User Validation
        do{
            System.out.println("Select the door (1, 2, or 3): ");
            user_door = scan.nextInt();
        }while(user_door > 3 || user_door < 0);
        do{
            open_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
        }while(open_door == prize_door || open_door == user_door);

        System.out.println("\nIn a moment, I will show you where the prize is located,");
        System.out.println("but first I will show you what is behind one of the other doors");
        System.out.println("\nBehind door number " + open_door+ " are goats!");
        System.out.println("You selected door number " + user_door);
        char userReply;
        do{
            System.out.println("\nWould you like to switch your door(y/n)? ");
            userReply = scan.next().charAt(0);
        }while(userReply!='y' && userReply!='n');       

        int user_duplicate = user_door;
        if (userReply == 'y') {
            do{
                user_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
            }while(user_door == open_door || user_door == user_duplicate);
        }

        System.out.println("The prize is behind door number: " + prize_door);

        if (user_door == prize_door) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You won the prize!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry. You lost.");
        }
    }
}
```

You should assign only the `prize_door` before getting `user_door`, after getting the `user_door` you have to assign the `open_door` and also the `other_door` if you choose to switch your door.

Comment: I got it working now per your suggestions and I saw where my mistake was, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Good @Lowki, btw use do while loop in your further java programs as it'll be very helpful to minimise your codes.

Answer (score 1):

Lets understand what your code does step by step with an example

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GameShow {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
Random generator = new Random();

// Initialize Variables
int user_door,
    open_door,
    other_door,
    prize_door;

// Generate random value 1-3
prize_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
```

Lets assume the generator assigns 2 to `price_door`

```
open_door = prize_door;

while(open_door == prize_door){
    open_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
}
```

Lets assume  after the loop the generator assigns 1 to `open_door`

```
other_door = open_door;

while (other_door == open_door || other_door == prize_door){
    other_door = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
}
```

Lets assume  after the loop the generator assigns 3 to `other_door`

```
// Begin Game
System.out.println("*** Welcome to the game show! ***");  
System.out.println("Select the door (1, 2, or 3): ");
```

Lets recall the values of the variables 
`open_door = 1` `other_door = 3` `prize_door = 2`

```
user_door = scan.nextInt();
// User Validation
    if (user_door > 3 || user_door < 0) {
        System.out.println("Please select door 1, 2, or 3");
        user_door = scan.nextInt();
    } else if(user_door == 1 || user_door == 2 ||  user_door == 3) {
```

Lets assume user enters 1  `user_door = 1`

```
//Continue Game
System.out.println("\nIn a moment, I will show you where the prize is located,");
System.out.println("but first I will show you what is behind one of the other doors");

//Continue Dialogue
System.out.println("\nBehind door number " + open_door + " are goats!");
```

Here you are opening Door 1 (`open_door = 1`) which is the same as the `user_door = 1`

**Which is wrong according to the logic of the game**

```
System.out.println("You selected door number " + user_door);
System.out.println("\nWould you like to switch your door(y/n)? ");

//User Input Yes or No
char userReply = scan.next().charAt(0);

//If statement with nested while statements for user input
    if (userReply == 'y'){
            user_door = other_door;
            } while(userReply != 'y' && userReply != 'n')
            {
                //User Validation
                System.out.println("Please enter either y/n");
                userReply = scan.next().charAt(0);
            } 

System.out.println("The prize is behind door number: " + prize_door); 

//Check to see if user won or lost
    if(user_door == prize_door){
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You won the prize!");
        } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry. You lost.");
                }       

    }
}
}
```

You need change the selection of doors based on the user's input because as a host you know where the car/gold is and where the goat is which missing in the program

You should fix the `prize_door` before the game starts which you are doing correct but the `open_door` and `other_door` should be decided based on the `user_door`

Comment: Alright I can see that I was missing the test on the user input, for this I can use a while loop like I did with the `prize_door` correct? 

Also, thank you for taking the time to help! Appreciate it

Comment: You are under the impression that the host(program) should not know where the prize and goats are which isn't true. The host always know where the prize is and where the goats are so the generator should be used the first time to fix the prize_door later based on the prize_door determine the other two doors (no need of loop and generator) and use them directly no need for the loop and generator a simple if will do the job something like `IF (prize_door == 1) other_doors[] = {2,3}`

Comment: I understand now where my mistake was, thank you helping me get a better grip on this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers, lots of things pointed out as wrong or ineffective (yet somehow noone comments on randomizing 3 elements in this way, instead of just shuffling them once based on a randomizer), but noone explicitly solved the question: "...except that I can't seem to get the user_door to switch to the other door.."

The three doors are labeled `prize_door`, `open_door`, and `other_door`. `user_door` can be any one of these. Which is wrong, but whatever.

```
if (userReply == 'y')
    user_door = other_door;
```

The statement used here changes `user_door` to the specific value of `other_door`(the non-prize closed door), without regarding what the value of `user_door` is. It **should** change it from `prize_door` to `other_door` and vice versa.

```
if (userReply == 'y')
{
    if (user_door == other_door)
        user_door = prize_door;
    else
        user_door = other_door;
}
```

Barring the case `user_door == open_door`, which should indeed not exist.